# Looping Recursive Function c++

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, tail-recursion, qsort

I am using Qsort, based on `employee.lastname`.

`left` is the counter of how many we've ran through.

`emptotal`, (or `right`) is how many total there are.

Since I know there are 5 I forced the pivot point to 3. My problem is, with the 2nd recursive call in the entire thing loops, and I can't figure out why it loops. It should count up (or down) then meet its end counter.

```
#include "./record.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

void externalSort(EmployeeRecord employee[],int empcount,int emptotal)
{
    int left=empcount,
        right=emptotal;    
    EmployeeRecord pivot = employee[3];    
    while (left < right) 
    {
        if (strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
        {    
            left++; 
        }
        else if (strcmp(employee[right].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
        {
            right--; 
        }
        else 
        {
            std::swap(employee[left],employee[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
    {
        std::swap(employee[left],employee[empcount]);
        left--;
    }
    if (strcmp(employee[right].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
    {
        std::swap(employee[right],employee[empcount]);
        right++;
    }

    if (empcount < right) externalSort(employee,empcount,right);
    if (left < emptotal) externalSort(employee,left,emptotal);
// The 2nd call is what seems to be looping, when I comment it out, 
    //the function doesn't loop.

}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Then please fix your grammar.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `std::sort`? Also note that the `externalSort` function is **not** *tail-recursion*

Comment: Tail recursion is a recursive strategy in which a function does some amount of work, then invokes itself. The "tail" refers to the fact that the recursion is at the very end of the function. externalSort Calls it self, and that call happens at the tail, how is that not Tail recursion? Also, I am not using std::sort, because it's not allowed in the scope I am working in.

Answer (score 1):

`employee[3]` picks the fourth thing, not the third thing, regardless of how many things it needs to sort.

The loop

```
while (left < right)
```

will check the items you have told it to check, but the pivot might not be in that range.

After you decide how to deal with that you have three further mistakes/things to think about.

1. Do you need to swap in the last branch?
2. When you recurse, try externalSort(employee,empcount,pivot_index-1)
3. Similar for the externalSort(employee,left, emptotal) you need to use the pivot index+1

There is some relatively clear psuedocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version). You assumed you could use the 3rd point each time. There may be less than 3 when you recurse.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check to make sure your strcmp statements are really doing what you think they should be doing.

```
if (strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
{    
left++; 
}
else if (strcmp(employee[right].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0 )
{
right--; 
}
```

I believe your left statement is correct, however you are checking if the last name at the right index is less than the pivot, when you probably should be checking if it is greater. Often times, small things like this will give you unexpected code-flow. I don't think this will fix everything however.

Comment: Here's a bit more info that you can use to make sure your algorithm is working correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version